# I am writing euclid's algorithm in VB.net but for some reason it is not working and i am pretty sure that my logic is right. where am i going wrong?

Tags: vb.net

It works completely fine if i put numbers which are divisible by each other(ex- 10 and 5, 20 and 10) but fails if numbers are not divisible with each other(ex- 44 and 46.
Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim num1, num2, temp, r As Integer
Function Algo(num1, num2)
    If (num1 > num2) Then
        temp = num2
        num2 = num1
        num1 = temp
    End If
    If (num2 Mod num1 = 0) Then
        Return num1
    Else
        r = num2 Mod num1
        num2 = num1
        num1 = r
        Algo(num1, num2)
    End If
End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a1, a2 As Integer
    a1 = Val(FirstNum.Text)
    a2 = Val(SecondNum.Text)
    GCD.Text = Val(Algo(a1, a2))
End Sub
```

it just shows 0 as an answer if numbers entered are not divisible:
End Class[Picture of the problem i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKAma.png)

Comment: You need to [learn how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). And you're not returning `Algo(num1, num2)`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the recursive approach?  There are simpler ones that use subtraction or division in a while loop.

Comment: @ParrishHusband yes professor told us to write this program recursively

Comment: @ChiragjotSingh okay that makes sense.  Also on top of the good answers you've gotten, make sure to define your function with the correct return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Algo(num1, num2)
```

Should be this instead:

```
Return Algo(num1, num2)
```

Your algo is (probably) fine, but when you go recursive it doesn't return anything, which is why you get a zero.

Have fun!

Comment: @ChiragjotSingh Please accept the answer provided by laancelot by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. Not will this help future readers but it will earn you a few reps.